# Apagar alguns resultados da array

Tags: php, array, delete

Preciso deixar na array abaixo somente os valores Sim: 1 e 2
Alguma sugestão? Tentei unset() mas não deu certo.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Adair' (length=26)
      1 => string '498' (length=3)
      2 => string 'Nao' (length=3)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Pedro' (length=31)
      1 => string '189' (length=3)
      2 => string 'Sim' (length=3)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Celso' (length=11)
      1 => string '651' (length=3)
      2 => string 'Sim' (length=3)
      3 => string 'E-mail: sdsd' (length=12)
```

Comment: Consegui com esse post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965541/filter-multidimensional-array-by-value-in-arra Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Use a função `array_filter` com uma função anônima para retornar os itens que contém o valor desejado.

**Exemplos**

Caso o valor "Sim" esteja sempre na posição 2 do subarray:

```
$novoArray = array_filter($seuArray, function($arr) {
    return $arr[2] == 'Sim';
})
```

Caso esteja em qualquer posição:

```
$novoArray = array_filter($seuArray, function($arr) {
    return in_array('Sim', $arr);
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, mas não rolou. $novo_valores = array_filter($valores, function($valor) { return $valor == 'Sim'; }); $novo_valores ficou vazia..

Comment: Só tome o cuidado que `$valor`, neste caso, é um *array* e não uma *string*. É preciso comparar um valor deste *array*, então o correto é fazer `return $valor[2] == 'Sim'`.

Comment: Corrigi e incluí outra alternativa. Funcionando.